# Plotly: styling secondary x axis

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-python

I have a `plotly` plot with a secondary x axis and am wondering if there's any way to style this axis, like one might do for the primary axis—e.g., change the number of ticks, the font, the text size, etc. (A [similar question](https://community.plotly.com/t/styling-multicategory-axis/47623) has been asked to no avail in the Plotly Community forums.)

Here is a minimally reproducible code snippet from a [related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61803438/python-plotly-figure-with-secondary-x-axis-linked-to-primary) SO question:

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots
from plotly.graph_objs.layout import YAxis,XAxis,Margin

layout = go.Layout(
    title="Double X Axis Example",
    xaxis=XAxis(
        title="Celcius"
    ),
    xaxis2 = XAxis(
        title="Fahrenheits",
        overlaying= 'x', 
        side= 'top',
    ),
    yaxis=dict(
        title="Y values"
    ),
)

# Create figure with secondary x-axis
fig = go.Figure(layout=layout)

# Add traces
fig.add_trace(
    go.Scatter(x=[10, 20, 30], y=[4.5, 6, 5], name="data set in celcius"),
)

fig.add_trace(
    go.Scatter(x=[40, 60, 80], y=[4, 5, 6.5], name="data set in fahrenheit", xaxis='x2'),
)

fig.show()
```

Is there a way to use `fig.update_xaxes()` perhaps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a lot that can be done for the `second x-axis`, in fact, since it is set in the same way as the original one, you can make these changes in the same way that you would with the first x-axis, which is by setting the parameters which you would like to change within the `xaxis2` in the `layout`.

For all of the options, you can refer to this list of valid properties of the XAxis:

```
Valid properties:
    anchor
        If set to an opposite-letter axis id (e.g. `x2`, `y`),
        this axis is bound to the corresponding opposite-letter
        axis. If set to "free", this axis' position is
        determined by `position`.
    automargin
        Determines whether long tick labels automatically grow
        the figure margins.
    autorange
        Determines whether or not the range of this axis is
        computed in relation to the input data. See `rangemode`
        for more info. If `range` is provided, then `autorange`
        is set to False.
    autotypenumbers
        Using "strict" a numeric string in trace data is not
        converted to a number. Using *convert types* a numeric
        string in trace data may be treated as a number during
        automatic axis `type` detection. Defaults to
        layout.autotypenumbers.
    calendar
        Sets the calendar system to use for `range` and `tick0`
        if this is a date axis. This does not set the calendar
        for interpreting data on this axis, that's specified in
        the trace or via the global `layout.calendar`
    categoryarray
        Sets the order in which categories on this axis appear.
        Only has an effect if `categoryorder` is set to
        "array". Used with `categoryorder`.
    categoryarraysrc
        Sets the source reference on Chart Studio Cloud for
        categoryarray .
    categoryorder
        Specifies the ordering logic for the case of
        categorical variables. By default, plotly uses "trace",
        which specifies the order that is present in the data
        supplied. Set `categoryorder` to *category ascending*
        or *category descending* if order should be determined
        by the alphanumerical order of the category names. Set
        `categoryorder` to "array" to derive the ordering from
        the attribute `categoryarray`. If a category is not
        found in the `categoryarray` array, the sorting
        behavior for that attribute will be identical to the
        "trace" mode. The unspecified categories will follow
        the categories in `categoryarray`. Set `categoryorder`
        to *total ascending* or *total descending* if order
        should be determined by the numerical order of the
        values. Similarly, the order can be determined by the
        min, max, sum, mean or median of all the values.
    color
        Sets default for all colors associated with this axis
        all at once: line, font, tick, and grid colors. Grid
        color is lightened by blending this with the plot
        background Individual pieces can override this.
    constrain
        If this axis needs to be compressed (either due to its
        own `scaleanchor` and `scaleratio` or those of the
        other axis), determines how that happens: by increasing
        the "range", or by decreasing the "domain". Default is
        "domain" for axes containing image traces, "range"
        otherwise.
    constraintoward
        If this axis needs to be compressed (either due to its
        own `scaleanchor` and `scaleratio` or those of the
        other axis), determines which direction we push the
        originally specified plot area. Options are "left",
        "center" (default), and "right" for x axes, and "top",
        "middle" (default), and "bottom" for y axes.
    dividercolor
        Sets the color of the dividers Only has an effect on
        "multicategory" axes.
    dividerwidth
        Sets the width (in px) of the dividers Only has an
        effect on "multicategory" axes.
    domain
        Sets the domain of this axis (in plot fraction).
    dtick
        Sets the step in-between ticks on this axis. Use with
        `tick0`. Must be a positive number, or special strings
        available to "log" and "date" axes. If the axis `type`
        is "log", then ticks are set every 10^(n*dtick) where n
        is the tick number. For example, to set a tick mark at
        1, 10, 100, 1000, ... set dtick to 1. To set tick marks
        at 1, 100, 10000, ... set dtick to 2. To set tick marks
        at 1, 5, 25, 125, 625, 3125, ... set dtick to
        log_10(5), or 0.69897000433. "log" has several special
        values; "L<f>", where `f` is a positive number, gives
        ticks linearly spaced in value (but not position). For
        example `tick0` = 0.1, `dtick` = "L0.5" will put ticks
        at 0.1, 0.6, 1.1, 1.6 etc. To show powers of 10 plus
        small digits between, use "D1" (all digits) or "D2"
        (only 2 and 5). `tick0` is ignored for "D1" and "D2".
        If the axis `type` is "date", then you must convert the
        time to milliseconds. For example, to set the interval
        between ticks to one day, set `dtick` to 86400000.0.
        "date" also has special values "M<n>" gives ticks
        spaced by a number of months. `n` must be a positive
        integer. To set ticks on the 15th of every third month,
        set `tick0` to "2000-01-15" and `dtick` to "M3". To set
        ticks every 4 years, set `dtick` to "M48"
    exponentformat
        Determines a formatting rule for the tick exponents.
        For example, consider the number 1,000,000,000. If
        "none", it appears as 1,000,000,000. If "e", 1e+9. If
        "E", 1E+9. If "power", 1x10^9 (with 9 in a super
        script). If "SI", 1G. If "B", 1B.
    fixedrange
        Determines whether or not this axis is zoom-able. If
        true, then zoom is disabled.
    gridcolor
        Sets the color of the grid lines.
    gridwidth
        Sets the width (in px) of the grid lines.
    hoverformat
        Sets the hover text formatting rule using d3 formatting
        mini-languages which are very similar to those in
        Python. For numbers, see:
        https://github.com/d3/d3-3.x-api-
        reference/blob/master/Formatting.md#d3_format And for
        dates see: https://github.com/d3/d3-time-
        format#locale_format We add one item to d3's date
        formatter: "%{n}f" for fractional seconds with n
        digits. For example, *2016-10-13 09:15:23.456* with
        tickformat "%H~%M~%S.%2f" would display "09~15~23.46"
    layer
        Sets the layer on which this axis is displayed. If
        *above traces*, this axis is displayed above all the
        subplot's traces If *below traces*, this axis is
        displayed below all the subplot's traces, but above the
        grid lines. Useful when used together with scatter-like
        traces with `cliponaxis` set to False to show markers
        and/or text nodes above this axis.
    linecolor
        Sets the axis line color.
    linewidth
        Sets the width (in px) of the axis line.
    matches
        If set to another axis id (e.g. `x2`, `y`), the range
        of this axis will match the range of the corresponding
        axis in data-coordinates space. Moreover, matching axes
        share auto-range values, category lists and histogram
        auto-bins. Note that setting axes simultaneously in
        both a `scaleanchor` and a `matches` constraint is
        currently forbidden. Moreover, note that matching axes
        must have the same `type`.
    minexponent
        Hide SI prefix for 10^n if |n| is below this number.
        This only has an effect when `tickformat` is "SI" or
        "B".
    mirror
        Determines if the axis lines or/and ticks are mirrored
        to the opposite side of the plotting area. If True, the
        axis lines are mirrored. If "ticks", the axis lines and
        ticks are mirrored. If False, mirroring is disable. If
        "all", axis lines are mirrored on all shared-axes
        subplots. If "allticks", axis lines and ticks are
        mirrored on all shared-axes subplots.
    nticks
        Specifies the maximum number of ticks for the
        particular axis. The actual number of ticks will be
        chosen automatically to be less than or equal to
        `nticks`. Has an effect only if `tickmode` is set to
        "auto".
    overlaying
        If set a same-letter axis id, this axis is overlaid on
        top of the corresponding same-letter axis, with traces
        and axes visible for both axes. If False, this axis
        does not overlay any same-letter axes. In this case,
        for axes with overlapping domains only the highest-
        numbered axis will be visible.
    position
        Sets the position of this axis in the plotting space
        (in normalized coordinates). Only has an effect if
        `anchor` is set to "free".
    range
        Sets the range of this axis. If the axis `type` is
        "log", then you must take the log of your desired range
        (e.g. to set the range from 1 to 100, set the range
        from 0 to 2). If the axis `type` is "date", it should
        be date strings, like date data, though Date objects
        and unix milliseconds will be accepted and converted to
        strings. If the axis `type` is "category", it should be
        numbers, using the scale where each category is
        assigned a serial number from zero in the order it
        appears.
    rangebreaks
        A tuple of
        :class:`plotly.graph_objects.layout.xaxis.Rangebreak`
        instances or dicts with compatible properties
    rangebreakdefaults
        When used in a template (as
        layout.template.layout.xaxis.rangebreakdefaults), sets
        the default property values to use for elements of
        layout.xaxis.rangebreaks
    rangemode
        If "normal", the range is computed in relation to the
        extrema of the input data. If *tozero*`, the range
        extends to 0, regardless of the input data If
        "nonnegative", the range is non-negative, regardless of
        the input data. Applies only to linear axes.
    rangeselector
        :class:`plotly.graph_objects.layout.xaxis.Rangeselector
        ` instance or dict with compatible properties
    rangeslider
        :class:`plotly.graph_objects.layout.xaxis.Rangeslider`
        instance or dict with compatible properties
    scaleanchor
        If set to another axis id (e.g. `x2`, `y`), the range
        of this axis changes together with the range of the
        corresponding axis such that the scale of pixels per
        unit is in a constant ratio. Both axes are still
        zoomable, but when you zoom one, the other will zoom
        the same amount, keeping a fixed midpoint. `constrain`
        and `constraintoward` determine how we enforce the
        constraint. You can chain these, ie `yaxis:
        {scaleanchor: *x*}, xaxis2: {scaleanchor: *y*}` but you
        can only link axes of the same `type`. The linked axis
        can have the opposite letter (to constrain the aspect
        ratio) or the same letter (to match scales across
        subplots). Loops (`yaxis: {scaleanchor: *x*}, xaxis:
        {scaleanchor: *y*}` or longer) are redundant and the
        last constraint encountered will be ignored to avoid
        possible inconsistent constraints via `scaleratio`.
        Note that setting axes simultaneously in both a
        `scaleanchor` and a `matches` constraint is currently
        forbidden.
    scaleratio
        If this axis is linked to another by `scaleanchor`,
        this determines the pixel to unit scale ratio. For
        example, if this value is 10, then every unit on this
        axis spans 10 times the number of pixels as a unit on
        the linked axis. Use this for example to create an
        elevation profile where the vertical scale is
        exaggerated a fixed amount with respect to the
        horizontal.
    separatethousands
        If "true", even 4-digit integers are separated
    showdividers
        Determines whether or not a dividers are drawn between
        the category levels of this axis. Only has an effect on
        "multicategory" axes.
    showexponent
        If "all", all exponents are shown besides their
        significands. If "first", only the exponent of the
        first tick is shown. If "last", only the exponent of
        the last tick is shown. If "none", no exponents appear.
    showgrid
        Determines whether or not grid lines are drawn. If
        True, the grid lines are drawn at every tick mark.
    showline
        Determines whether or not a line bounding this axis is
        drawn.
    showspikes
        Determines whether or not spikes (aka droplines) are
        drawn for this axis. Note: This only takes affect when
        hovermode = closest
    showticklabels
        Determines whether or not the tick labels are drawn.
    showtickprefix
        If "all", all tick labels are displayed with a prefix.
        If "first", only the first tick is displayed with a
        prefix. If "last", only the last tick is displayed with
        a suffix. If "none", tick prefixes are hidden.
    showticksuffix
        Same as `showtickprefix` but for tick suffixes.
    side
        Determines whether a x (y) axis is positioned at the
        "bottom" ("left") or "top" ("right") of the plotting
        area.
    spikecolor
        Sets the spike color. If undefined, will use the series
        color
    spikedash
        Sets the dash style of lines. Set to a dash type string
        ("solid", "dot", "dash", "longdash", "dashdot", or
        "longdashdot") or a dash length list in px (eg
        "5px,10px,2px,2px").
    spikemode
        Determines the drawing mode for the spike line If
        "toaxis", the line is drawn from the data point to the
        axis the  series is plotted on. If "across", the line
        is drawn across the entire plot area, and supercedes
        "toaxis". If "marker", then a marker dot is drawn on
        the axis the series is plotted on
    spikesnap
        Determines whether spikelines are stuck to the cursor
        or to the closest datapoints.
    spikethickness
        Sets the width (in px) of the zero line.
    tick0
        Sets the placement of the first tick on this axis. Use
        with `dtick`. If the axis `type` is "log", then you
        must take the log of your starting tick (e.g. to set
        the starting tick to 100, set the `tick0` to 2) except
        when `dtick`=*L<f>* (see `dtick` for more info). If the
        axis `type` is "date", it should be a date string, like
        date data. If the axis `type` is "category", it should
        be a number, using the scale where each category is
        assigned a serial number from zero in the order it
        appears.
    tickangle
        Sets the angle of the tick labels with respect to the
        horizontal. For example, a `tickangle` of -90 draws the
        tick labels vertically.
    tickcolor
        Sets the tick color.
    tickfont
        Sets the tick font.
    tickformat
        Sets the tick label formatting rule using d3 formatting
        mini-languages which are very similar to those in
        Python. For numbers, see:
        https://github.com/d3/d3-3.x-api-
        reference/blob/master/Formatting.md#d3_format And for
        dates see: https://github.com/d3/d3-time-
        format#locale_format We add one item to d3's date
        formatter: "%{n}f" for fractional seconds with n
        digits. For example, *2016-10-13 09:15:23.456* with
        tickformat "%H~%M~%S.%2f" would display "09~15~23.46"
    tickformatstops
        A tuple of :class:`plotly.graph_objects.layout.xaxis.Ti
        ckformatstop` instances or dicts with compatible
        properties
    tickformatstopdefaults
        When used in a template (as
        layout.template.layout.xaxis.tickformatstopdefaults),
        sets the default property values to use for elements of
        layout.xaxis.tickformatstops
    ticklabelmode
        Determines where tick labels are drawn with respect to
        their corresponding ticks and grid lines. Only has an
        effect for axes of `type` "date" When set to "period",
        tick labels are drawn in the middle of the period
        between ticks.
    ticklabelposition
        Determines where tick labels are drawn with respect to
        the axis Please note that top or bottom has no effect
        on x axes or when `ticklabelmode` is set to "period".
        Similarly left or right has no effect on y axes or when
        `ticklabelmode` is set to "period". Has no effect on
        "multicategory" axes or when `tickson` is set to
        "boundaries". When used on axes linked by `matches` or
        `scaleanchor`, no extra padding for inside labels would
        be added by autorange, so that the scales could match.
    ticklen
        Sets the tick length (in px).
    tickmode
        Sets the tick mode for this axis. If "auto", the number
        of ticks is set via `nticks`. If "linear", the
        placement of the ticks is determined by a starting
        position `tick0` and a tick step `dtick` ("linear" is
        the default value if `tick0` and `dtick` are provided).
        If "array", the placement of the ticks is set via
        `tickvals` and the tick text is `ticktext`. ("array" is
        the default value if `tickvals` is provided).
    tickprefix
        Sets a tick label prefix.
    ticks
        Determines whether ticks are drawn or not. If "", this
        axis' ticks are not drawn. If "outside" ("inside"),
        this axis' are drawn outside (inside) the axis lines.
    tickson
        Determines where ticks and grid lines are drawn with
        respect to their corresponding tick labels. Only has an
        effect for axes of `type` "category" or
        "multicategory". When set to "boundaries", ticks and
        grid lines are drawn half a category to the left/bottom
        of labels.
    ticksuffix
        Sets a tick label suffix.
    ticktext
        Sets the text displayed at the ticks position via
        `tickvals`. Only has an effect if `tickmode` is set to
        "array". Used with `tickvals`.
    ticktextsrc
        Sets the source reference on Chart Studio Cloud for
        ticktext .
    tickvals
        Sets the values at which ticks on this axis appear.
        Only has an effect if `tickmode` is set to "array".
        Used with `ticktext`.
    tickvalssrc
        Sets the source reference on Chart Studio Cloud for
        tickvals .
    tickwidth
        Sets the tick width (in px).
    title
        :class:`plotly.graph_objects.layout.xaxis.Title`
        instance or dict with compatible properties
    titlefont
        Deprecated: Please use layout.xaxis.title.font instead.
        Sets this axis' title font. Note that the title's font
        used to be customized by the now deprecated `titlefont`
        attribute.
    type
        Sets the axis type. By default, plotly attempts to
        determined the axis type by looking into the data of
        the traces that referenced the axis in question.
    uirevision
        Controls persistence of user-driven changes in axis
        `range`, `autorange`, and `title` if in `editable:
        true` configuration. Defaults to `layout.uirevision`.
    visible
        A single toggle to hide the axis while preserving
        interaction like dragging. Default is true when a
        cheater plot is present on the axis, otherwise false
    zeroline
        Determines whether or not a line is drawn at along the
        0 value of this axis. If True, the zero line is drawn
        on top of the grid lines.
    zerolinecolor
        Sets the line color of the zero line.
    zerolinewidth
        Sets the width (in px) of the zero line.
```

As for an example, you can do something like this to change the steps in between the ticks, the text size and font:

**The Code:**

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots
from plotly.graph_objs.layout import YAxis,XAxis,Margin

layout = go.Layout(
    title="Double X Axis Example",
    xaxis=XAxis(
        title="Celcius"
    ),
    xaxis2 = XAxis(
        overlaying= 'x', 
        dtick = 7,
        title = {'text': "Fahrenheits", 'font_family': 'Arial', 'font_size': 12, 'font_color': 'green'},
        side= 'top',
    ),
    yaxis=dict(
        title="Y values"
    ),
)

# Create figure with secondary x-axis
fig = go.Figure(layout=layout)

# Add traces
fig.add_trace(
    go.Scatter(x=[10, 20, 30], y=[4.5, 6, 5], name="data set in celcius"),
)

fig.add_trace(
    go.Scatter(x=[40, 60, 80], y=[4, 5, 6.5], name="data set in fahrenheit", xaxis='x2'),
)

fig.show()
```

**The Graph:**
[image]

Comment: This is perfect—thank you! I should note that calling `fig.update_xaxes()` after initiating the figure with `layout` seems effectively to erase any styling done via `layout` initially. So style in `layout` all at once.